# getting two matrices in one line

Tags: latex, matrix

im trying to get these to appear in the same line without any success, my coding is

```
\begin{equation}
P^+=\[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\end{array} \right)\]
P^-=\[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1\end{array} \right)\]
\end{equation}
```

any hints or suggestions would be welcome

Comment: NB. pavium's reformat changes the semantics of cal's question

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of all the `\[` and `\]`, and add some space between them:

```
\begin{equation}
P^+= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\end{array} \right)\qquad
P^-= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 6):

With the [AMS-LaTeX](http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.html) package, you can accomplish this task more conveniently with the `align` and `pmatrix` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
P^+ &= \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
&
P^- &= \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```